# How to select several element from an RDD file line using Spark in Scala

Tags: scala, variables, apache-spark, selection, rdd

I'm new in spark and scala and I would like to select several columns from a dataset.

I transformed my data in RDD a file using :

```
val dataset = sc.textFile(args(0))
```

Then I split my line

```
val resu = dataset.map(line => line.split("\001"))
```

But I in my dataset I have a lot of features and I just want to keep some of then (colums 2 and 3)

I tried this (which works with Pyspark) but It does'nt work.

```
val resu = dataset.map(line => line.split("\001")[2,3])
```

I know this is a newbie question but is there someone who can help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I just want to keep some of then (colums 2 and 3)

If you want columns 2 and 3 in `tuple` form you can do

```
val resu = dataset.map(line => {
  val array = line.split("\001")
  (array(2), array(3))
})
```

But if you want column 2 and 3 in `array` form then you can do

```
val resu = dataset.map(line => {
  val array = line.split("\001")
  Array(array(2), array(3))
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, in order to access to specific list elements you have to use parentheses.

In your case, you want a sublist, so you can try the slice(i, j) function. It extracts the elements from the index i to the j-1. So in your case, you may use:

```
val resu = dataset.map(line => line.split("\001").slice(2,4))
```

Hope it helps.